# Android kernel building on linux

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

For create a bootable android image ,
I built linux kernel with     `./build.sh -p sun4i_crane -k 3.0` clearly.
Then for Building Android Sources set the environment    `source build/envsetup.sh`
For select a platform  “lunch” command

```
root@arge16-HP-600B:/home/arge1-6/workspace/extroid/android4.0# lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. full-eng
     2. full_x86-eng
     3. vbox_x86-eng
     4. full_maguro-userdebug
     5. full_tuna-userdebug
     6. crane_3g-eng
     7. crane_evb_mmc
     8. crane_m1003h6-eng
     9. crane_MID9742_sc3052-userdebug
     10. full_panda-eng
```

Select for mmc, number 7 then I got this warning below

```
Which would you like? [full-eng] 7

** Invalid variant: 'crane_evb_mmc'
** Must be one of user userdebug eng
```

I found this     `crane_evb_mmc` this file a makefile and changed it `crane_evb` 
then I got this warning this time

```
Which would you like? [full-eng] 7
build/core/product_config.mk:193: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/softwinner/crane-evb_mmc/crane_evb_mmc.mk]]: "device/softwinner/crane-evb_mmc/crane_evb_mmc.mk" does not exist.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'crane_evb_mmc'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

** Invalid variant: 'crane_evb_mmc'
** Must be one of user userdebug eng
```

I search for this and there is a solution I edit my AndroidProducts.mk  as below but no chages there

```
PRODUCT_MAKEFILES := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/crane_evb_mmc.mk \
```

Anyone has a suggesstion?

Comment: answer to your question is in this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do

Comment: thanks @m-ric    I will get this book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lunch` expects that you supply a board (`crane_evb_mmc`) along with a build variant `{user,userdebug,eng}`. Supplying only the board is not enough. Try:

```
$ lunch crane_evb_mmc-eng
```